# How can I ensure either 0 or 2 updates work in a stored procedure with 2 updates?

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have a stored procedure running in a SQL Azure database on the cloud that looks like this. Note that I simplified it for this question to make it easy to fit on the page:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mark_test 
   @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT,
   @RC           INT OUTPUT 
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
   UPDATE UserTest SET A = 99 WHERE B = 98;
   IF (@@ROWCOUNT != 1) THROW 50001,'UserTest - Problem setting A',1
   UPDATE UserTest SET B = 99 WHERE C = 98;
   IF (@@ROWCOUNT != 1) THROW 50002,'UserTest - Problem setting B',1
   SET @RC = 0
   RETURN 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH   
   SET @RC = 1
   SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
   RETURN
END CATCH  
END
```

What I would like is for either no update to take place or both updates to take place.  Can someone give me some advice on how I can do this.

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?

Comment: Wrap your TRY in a [TRANSACTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use SQL Server transactions to make both statements are either successful or rollback. See below code and this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx) for details.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mark_test 
   @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT,
   @RC           INT OUTPUT 
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
   BEGIN TRANSACTION

   UPDATE UserTest SET A = 99 WHERE B = 98;
   IF (@@ROWCOUNT != 1) THROW 50001,'UserTest - Problem setting A',1
   UPDATE UserTest SET B = 99 WHERE C = 98;
   IF (@@ROWCOUNT != 1) THROW 50002,'UserTest - Problem setting B',1
   SET @RC = 0

   COMMIT TRANSACTION
   RETURN 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH   
   SET @RC = 1
   SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   RETURN
END CATCH  
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to test for favorable conditions before doing anything, like this psuedocode:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mark_test 
   @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT,
   @RC           INT OUTPUT 
AS
BEGIN

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UserTest WHERE B=98)
   AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UserTest WHERE C=98)

   BEGIN
   {Perform Both Updates}
   SET @RC = 0
   RETURN 
   END
ELSE 
   SET @RC=1

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UserTest WHERE B=98)
     {Set the Error Message regarding "B"}
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UserTest WHERE C=98)
     {Set the Error Message regarding "C"}
RETURN 
END
```